# Why to use the Callendar equation instead of the temperature coefficient differential equation?

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, electrical-resistance, measurements, instrument

[The temperature coefficient differential law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient) gives an equation for the temperature coefficient $\alpha$, which describes the relative change of a physical property $R$ that is associated with a given change in temperature:

$$\frac{dR}{R}=\alpha dT \tag{1}$$

This ODE can be solved to give

$$R(T)=R_0e^{\alpha(T-T_0)}, \tag{2}$$

with $R(T_0)=R_0$. This expression can be approximated by applying the Taylor series for the exponential function,

$$R\left(T\right)=R_0\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\alpha\left(T-T_0\right)\right)^k}{k!}\approx\ R_0\left(1+\alpha\left(T-T_0\right)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\left(T-T_0\right)^2\right). \tag{3}$$

If we stop at the first-order expansion, we get the well-known equation for the temperature dependence of resistances, $R\left(T\right)=R_0\left(1+\alpha\left(T-T_0\right)\right)$.

However, for RTD temperature sensors, the [Callendar-Van Dusen equation](https://www.newport.com/medias/sys_master/images/images/h97/h74/9163083317278/TN-RTD-1-Callendar-Van-Dusen-Equation-and-RTD-Temperature-Sensors.pdf) is used instead of equation (4). If we restrict ourselves, for simplicity, to temperatures $0ºC<T$, the Callendar equation applies:

$$R(T)=\mathcal{R_0}\left( 1+AT+BT^2 \right)\tag{4}$$

with $\mathcal{R_0}$ the resistance at $0$ ºC. We see that by rearranging the RHS of equation (3) we get a similar expression to (4):

$$R\left(T\right)=R_0\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}T_0\alpha-1\right)T_0\alpha+\left(1-T_0\alpha\right)\alpha T+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2T^2\right). \tag{5}$$

So my question is: if (5), which is an approximation, is similar to the Callendar equation (4), what's the point of using the Callendar equation instead of the exact equation (2)?